# How to store variable in phone memory android?

Tags: android

i need to store a variable in phone memory, and later get that variable to show it.

Please, give me some information or anything to search. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static SharedPreferences settings;
static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
settings = this.getPreferences(MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("Variablenname_1", "1");
editor.commit();
```

if you want so get the value use:

```
String val = settings.getString("Variablenname_1", "0");
```

Comment: Thanks, i am going to try with FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput

Comment: you only will be able to store simle datatypes in preferences, if you have a fos, why don't you store it as File?

Answer (score 2):

I think Shared Preferences is a good idea for you, read this for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Perfect, i think i should to use FileOutputStream

Comment: Could you post your variable description? It's hard to say what'll be the best without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

The final result.

```
SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String text = app_preferences.getString("name", "default");
...

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
editor.putString("name",name.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```